# How to get Total Overdraft amounts from a particular Date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get the total amount of overdraft accounts from an old Date, the goal is to get the total amount it was on the 31st of January.

I have the following tables Users and Transactions.

USERS (currently)

```
| user_id |  name   | account_balance  |
|---------|---------|------------------|
|     1   |  Wells  |    1.00          |
|     2   |  John   |    -10.00        |
|     3   |  Sahar  |    -5.00         |
|     4   |  Peter  |    1.00          |
```

TRANSACTIONS (daily transition can go back in time)

```
|  trans_id  | user_id |  amount_tendered  |   trans_datetime    |
|------------|---------|-------------------|---------------------|
|    1       |    1    |       2           |     2021-02-16      |
|    2       |    2    |       3           |     2021-02-16      |
|    3       |    3    |       5           |     2021-02-16      |
|    4       |    4    |       2           |     2021-02-16      |
|    5       |    1    |       10          |     2021-02-15      |
```

so the current total overdraft amount is

```
SELECT sum(account_balance) AS O_D_Amount 
FROM users 
WHERE account_balance < 0;

| O_D_Amount |
|------------|
|  -15       |
```

I need Help to reverse this amount to a date in history.

Comment: Please explain what you mean.  Desired results would help.  What do the transactions have to do with the user data?  There seems to be no relationship.

Comment: I need to get account balances from a particular date... 
that is I need help to reverse the transactions done and get what the user's account balance was as of an old date. So to produce only the total in overdraft as of a chosen date

Comment: if the total overdraft today is (-15) what was it on the 2021-01-31 so we need to add back all transactions done between now and 2021-01-31 then get the total in overdraft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming overdrafts are based on the sum of transactions up to a point, you can use a subquery:

```
select sum(total) as total_overdraft
from (select user_id, sum(amount_tendered) as total
      from transactions t
      where t.trans_datetime <= ?
      group by user_id
     ) t
where total < 0;
```

The `?` is a parameter placeholder for the date/time you care about.

Comment: Thanks,
When user makes a transaction the user account balances reduces,
I need to get the total that was accumulated on a particular date

Comment: if the total overdraft today is (-15), what was it on the 2021-01-31?  so we need to add back all transactions done between now and  2021-01-31 then get the total in overdraft

Comment: @Wells . . . Instead, this starts at the beginning of time and calculates all the transactions moving forward.

Comment: The account balance is stored on the users, that's the one that goes into overdraft... every time the user makes a transaction the account balance reduces by the amount tendered. SO I need to get how the account was on the 31st